# How do I enable microphone "sidetone" in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

One of the main reasons I prefer gaming on Windows rather than Linux is that the Logitech driver (for windows) allows me to enable microphone "sidetone". When sidetone is tuned up, I can hear myself when talking in the microphone, which makes using the headset for long periods of time much less uncomfortable.

To specify; what I'm looking for is a setting or application that makes the sound input feed directly to the sound output with **no delay**, at an adjustable volume.

Would this be possible to achieve in Linux? I'm using pulseaudio 4.0 and a Logitech G930 wireless headset.

<sub>Full disclosure - I'm actually using Debian with Cinnamon, but I also had this issue in Ubuntu and I'm betting that most solutions will work on both systems.</sub>

---

#### What have I tried?

I've tried using `pacat` to record and pipe the microphone input to the default output device:

```
pacat -r -d alsa_input.usb-Logitech_Logitech_G930_Headset-00-Headset.analog-mono | pacat -p --volume=20000 --latency-mc=1 --process-time-msec=1
```

But with all the latency-related options set to their minimum, I still get a ~0.25 sec delay from input to output.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you still have the Problem. But I've written a little "driver" which allows to adjust the Sidetone setting under linux (You can even set it louder than on windows!).
https://github.com/Sapd/G930SideTone

Comment: That looks awesome! I'll try it out the next time I'm on Linux. I'm currently on Windows because I can't get Debian or Ubuntu to install on a M.2 drive.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
   alsamixer;
```

...then F6 key on your keyboard to select soundcard. Unmute the sidetone channel with "m."

This works on Razer Kraken headsets.